# Building Docker image as non-root user

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

When building a Docker image, as a best practice, I understand I should not use the `root` user but I'm having a hard time with the user I created.

Here my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:3.9.2
RUN addgroup -S cetacean && adduser -S mobydick -G cetacean
USER mobydick
RUN apk update
```

And Here the error I get when I run it

> ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
>
> ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied

What am I supposed to do in order to be able to install packages using `mobydick`?

Answer (score 5):

As per best practices, if possible we should run docker container as non-root user.
We can do that by adding the user at the end so that you can install all the packages as root and when container starts, it uses non-root user.

```
 FROM alpine:3.9.2
 RUN addgroup -S cetacean && adduser -S mobydick -G cetacean
 RUN apk update 
 USER mobydick
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's definitely a possible way to go.

Comment: With some base images, you will need to run `RUN addgroup --system cetacean && adduser --system mobydick --ingroup cetacean` instead, to avoid errors like `Option s id ambiguous`.